# Is it possible to limit the scheduler to one actor in Akka.Net

Tags: c#, .net-core, akka.net

I need to send a message to actor on periodic bases. Based on the cluster configurations, there are 3 nodes available. So every actor in the node is scheduling the message. But I want one actor to do this job so that I can avoid reprocessing and duplicate processing.

Is there any way that we can schedule a message or a task from Cluster or any other way to solve this problem.

Comment: Wait a minute.  Surely Akka already has a mechanism to prevent this.  In an Actor model, generally one of the 3 nodes will grab the task from the queue and process it, making it unavailable to the remaining nodes.

Comment: It is not the task. I'm doing as below         Context.System.Scheduler
                .ScheduleTellRepeatedly(_interval, _interval, Self, new SendOutMessage(), Self);
        }

Comment: The message then.  There should be a way to configure Akka so that only one actor processes the message.  If that is not possible, find the [pattern](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/interaction-patterns.html) that assigns incoming messages to a single available actor for processing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make a [cluster singleton](https://getakka.net/articles/clustering/cluster-singleton.html), that way you will only have one of that actor type. For scheduling you can use [Quartz Actor](https://github.com/akkadotnet/Akka.Quartz.Actor)

Comment: Quartz actor will not solve my problem as my application will have multiple nodes and making cluster as singleton , is not an option for me